# .NET Core Global Variable not getting initial settings

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am creating a global variable, but first I need to initialize it with data.  The variable seems to be working, however, initialized data are not being set. Here is my `ConfigureServices`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddOptions();
    //Gets data for the Global variable
    MyOptions opt = SetValues();
    Action<MyOptions> options = (set => set = opt);
    services.Configure(options);
    services.Configure<MyOptions>(options);
    services.AddSingleton(resolver => resolver.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MyOptions>>().Value);
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

Then in the different controllers, I am calling it like this;

```
public ValuesController(IOptions<MyOptions> options)
{
    Options = settings.Value;
}
```

In testing the controllers can changes properties in `Options`, however, the settings are done in `MyOptions opt = SetValues();` are not there.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think this is necessary to use built-in options pattern in this case.

This code does not use it's benefits (e.g. reading settings from appsettings).

You can register MyOptions instance as a Singleton without using IOptions wrapper (like below).

```cs
services.AddSingleton(opt);
```

The better way to use this feature would be to put options from your settings into **appsetting.json**.

[Help link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: Thank that did it!